# Apropriate test for changes in proportion

Tags: proportion

I have a mixture of 5 viruses (similar amounts for each) as an input pool. I then passage this Input pool mixture in different cell lines reading the output, and want to see if the change in the proportion of virus 1 is significant.

How should I do this? Should I do t-tests of Output1 vs input, Output2 vs input, etc and then do some sort of FDR?

The data looks something like this:
[image]

I see that Virus1 always is most abundant after the Input pool mixture is allowed to replicate independently in 7 different cancer cell lines. What is the best to test this hypothesis? Thanks.

Comment: Do you only care about the proportion of virus 1 versus not virus 1, or does it matter how much virus 2, 3, etc are in each mix?

Comment: I want to focus on virus 1.